# Send iPhone's Unique Identifier (UDID) to a Remote Server using Phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch

**How do i Send this "UDID" to a remote REST API. ? Any Scripts ?, i am using following script to get Unique Identifier (UDID) using Phonegap**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.phonegap + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>
```

Loading device properties...

**How do i Send this "UDID" to a remote REST API. ? Any Scripts ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a ajax request to the api?
You can then specify the `get` and `post` parameters and put the `UDID` in it.

**Edit:**
Some good documentation with an example:
 http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/rich-user-experience.html

Comment: Hi, not sure how to use Ajax here, can you advise point out to any code ?